# HLSL Code for creating simplex noise[UE Custom Node]

Tags: unreal-engine4, hlsl, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I have the simplex noise plugin for UE4, however it does not match with the simplex noise material node[I need to create the same results from both BP and materials for offsetting a mesh and enabling collision through BP, similar to how you would set up collision for Gerstner waves]. How would I implement simplex noise in HLSL, I found a few programs online, but they fail when plugged into the custom node in the material and give an error. Below is the code I'm using, can someone tell me why it isn't working and how to fix it?

```
float3 mod289(float3 x) {
    return x - floor(x * (1.0 / 289.0)) * 289.0;
}

float2 mod289(float2 x) {
    return x - floor(x * (1.0 / 289.0)) * 289.0;
}

float3 permute(float3 x) {
    return mod289((x * 34.0 + 1.0) * x);
}

float3 taylorInvSqrt(float3 r) {
    return 1.79284291400159 - 0.85373472095314 * r;
}

// output noise is in range [-1, 1]
float snoise(float2 v) {
    const float4 C = float4(0.211324865405187,  // (3.0-sqrt(3.0))/6.0
                            0.366025403784439,  // 0.5*(sqrt(3.0)-1.0)
                            -0.577350269189626, // -1.0 + 2.0 * C.x
                            0.024390243902439); // 1.0 / 41.0

    // First corner
    float2 i  = floor(v + dot(v, C.yy));
    float2 x0 = v -   i + dot(i, C.xx);

    // Other corners
    float2 i1;
    i1.x = step(x0.y, x0.x);
    i1.y = 1.0 - i1.x;

    // x1 = x0 - i1  + 1.0 * C.xx;
    // x2 = x0 - 1.0 + 2.0 * C.xx;
    float2 x1 = x0 + C.xx - i1;
    float2 x2 = x0 + C.zz;

    // Permutations
    i = mod289(i); // Avoid truncation effects in permutation
    float3 p =
      permute(permute(i.y + float3(0.0, i1.y, 1.0))
                    + i.x + float3(0.0, i1.x, 1.0));

    float3 m = max(0.5 - float3(dot(x0, x0), dot(x1, x1), dot(x2, x2)), 0.0);
    m = m * m;
    m = m * m;

    // Gradients: 41 points uniformly over a line, mapped onto a diamond.
    // The ring size 17*17 = 289 is close to a multiple of 41 (41*7 = 287)
    float3 x = 2.0 * frac(p * C.www) - 1.0;
    float3 h = abs(x) - 0.5;
    float3 ox = floor(x + 0.5);
    float3 a0 = x - ox;

    // Normalise gradients implicitly by scaling m
    m *= taylorInvSqrt(a0 * a0 + h * h);

    // Compute final noise value at P
    float3 g = float3(
        a0.x * x0.x + h.x * x0.y,
        a0.y * x1.x + h.y * x1.y,
        g.z = a0.z * x2.x + h.z * x2.y
    );
    return 130.0 * dot(m, g);
}

float snoise01(float2 v) {
    return snoise(v) * 0.5 + 0.5;
}
```